# Andengine - Attaching sprite to parallax background still causes it to repeat

Tags: android, andengine

I am developing a game in `AndEngine` and I want to attach a sprite to a parallax background (on my main menu) BUT I don't want the sprite to be repeated (which is what is currently happening).

I have tried this (below) which works but I use the sprites in the game so when I come back to the main menu, the sprites will have moved (I tried resetting the sprites but doesn't seem to be working).

```
Sprite playerCar = new Sprite(playerX, playerY,
            mResourceManager.mPlayerCarTextureRegion,
            mVertexBufferObjectManager);
    playerCar.setRotation(-15);
    attachChild(playerCar);
```

What I want to do is the following:

Define my sprite as normal:

```
Sprite playerCar = new Sprite(playerX, playerY,
            mResourceManager.mPlayerCarTextureRegion,
            mVertexBufferObjectManager);
    playerCar.setRotation(-15);
```

Then attach it to my background:

```
ParallaxBackground menuParallaxBackground = new ParallaxBackground(0,
            0, 0);

    menuParallaxBackground.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(0,
            new Sprite(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT
                    - mResourceManager.mParallaxLayerRoad.getHeight(),
                    mResourceManager.mParallaxLayerRoad,
                    mVertexBufferObjectManager)));

    menuParallaxBackground.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(0,
            playerCar));
```

Which also works but the car keeps on repeating which I do not want.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the onManagedDraw method of the parallax classes then you will see why every entity attached to a ParallaxEntity is repeated!

Comment: Did you try to simply attach it to the  background simply by menuParallaxBackground.attachChild() ? Did not check if this is possible, just an idea...

Comment: @sjkm Ah yeah the while loop in onDraw - `while(currentMaxX < cameraWidth);` @ŁukaszMotyczka As far as I am aware you can only attach Parallax Entities. I will look into it further

Comment: @sij_a Yeah, exactly ;). Simply add a list to the class that holds other entities like the one you want to draw and draw them before the parallax entitites.

Comment: @sjkm hmm alright, I was originally thinking of extending (or copying) the class and creating my own method to just draw sprites once. Cheers, will try this tonight.

Comment: Fixed! just created a custom ParallaxBackground class and removed the while loop, used that for my main menu and the sprites are only getting rendered once! Cheers guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was because of the onDraw method on the ParallaxEntity class in the ParallaxBackground class. There was a loop around where the sprites get drawn that keeps going until the sprites fill up the width of the screen. I simply created a custom class and removed the while loop so I could use it for my Main Menu.

ParallaxEntity onDraw code before:

```
public void onDraw(final GLState pGLState, final Camera pCamera, final float pParallaxValue) {
        pGLState.pushModelViewGLMatrix();
        {
            final float cameraWidth = pCamera.getWidth();
            final float shapeWidthScaled = this.mAreaShape.getWidthScaled();
            float baseOffset = (pParallaxValue * this.mParallaxFactor) % shapeWidthScaled;

            while(baseOffset > 0) {
                baseOffset -= shapeWidthScaled;
            }
            pGLState.translateModelViewGLMatrixf(baseOffset, 0, 0);

            float currentMaxX = baseOffset;

            do {
                this.mAreaShape.onDraw(pGLState, pCamera);
                pGLState.translateModelViewGLMatrixf(shapeWidthScaled, 0, 0);
                currentMaxX += shapeWidthScaled;
            } while(currentMaxX < cameraWidth);
        }
        pGLState.popModelViewGLMatrix();
    }
```

my CustomParallaxEntity onDraw code after (notice the last while loop removed):

```
public void onDraw(final GLState pGLState, final Camera pCamera,
            final float pParallaxValue) {
        pGLState.pushModelViewGLMatrix();
        {
            final float shapeWidthScaled = this.mAreaShape.getWidthScaled();
            float baseOffset = (pParallaxValue * this.mParallaxFactor)
                    % shapeWidthScaled;

            while (baseOffset > 0) {
                baseOffset -= shapeWidthScaled;
            }
            pGLState.translateModelViewGLMatrixf(baseOffset, 0, 0);

            this.mAreaShape.onDraw(pGLState, pCamera);
            pGLState.translateModelViewGLMatrixf(shapeWidthScaled, 0, 0);
        }
        pGLState.popModelViewGLMatrix();
    }
```

Thanks to the comments on my question for helping me figure out a solution.